# What is the impact of setting PassengerAppRoot on the Apache server config level?

Tags: apache, passenger

What is the impact of setting `PassengerAppRoot` on the Apache server config level? I assume if I set it for vhost it works only when I access server via specific URL hostname. But if set on global level - each vhost will be affected? What's the expected behavior?

Comment: As a general rule, virtual hosts inherit directives from server configuration unless there is one specified in vhost configuration, which then takes precedence.

Comment: So I thought, but I've got few vhosts configured (plus, as described, PassengerAppRoot set in main `httpd.conf`) and somehow it loads Rails web app only when accessing server using only one of this vhosts. Others loads normal pages (static HTML and PHP.)